# Calculating a field error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, esri-geodatabase, python-parser, error-999999

I have this table:

[image: Initial table]

And I want to create a field called "COSN2" which after the creation I want to fill it with three characters from the field "COS207".
Than I wrote the following script:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env, UpdateCursor
from arcpy.management import AddField

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace="C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Trabalho AE\Trabalho.gdb"
fc="COS2007"

arcpy.AddField_management(fc,"COSN2","TEXT","","","","NULLABLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"COSN2","LEFT([CONS2007],3)","VB")

cursor=arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    print row.COS2007+" ; "+row.COSN2
```

Then the eclipse returns me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\MSIGOT\AE\AnaliseEsp\TrabalhoAE\COSN2.py", line 10, in <module>

arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"COSN2","LEFT([CONS2007],3)","VB")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3360, in CalculateField
raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

I've tried to change "VB" (above) to "PYTHON" and "PYTHON_9.3" but the error persists.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.  Your field name in your screenshot is `COS2007` but in your python you've called it `CONS2007`

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"COSN2","LEFT([CONS2007],3)","VB")
                                                    ^
```

Also note that you have created your new field `CONS2` with an *alias* of `NULLABLE`

You need to add another `""` before the `"NULLABLE"`

```
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "COSN2", "TEXT", "", "", "", "NULLABLE")
```

should probably be

```
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, "COSN2", "TEXT", "", "", "", "","NULLABLE")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'm a beginner and this errors is have happened somtimes... xD